# c# asp.net send mail issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, popup

I have create one web application where user can send friend request. If there are two users **A** and **B**. If **A** user send friend request to **B** then one pop up display's on **B** user dashboard. In that pop up box two buttons are there **confirm** or **ignore**.

If user click on **confirm** button then it takes some time to close that popup box. Because in backgroud it execute code for send email. Once email sent then that popup box close. So I want to close that popup box immediately after clicking on **confirm** button and then after send mail to that user.

Here is my code for **accepting request and sending mail**

```
#region dlUserFriendRequests_ItemCommand
    protected void dlUserFriendRequests_ItemCommand(object source, DataListCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        HtmlTable objDataTable;
        //Panel objDataTable;
        switch (e.CommandName)
        {
            case "confirm":
                RadioButtonList objRadioButtonList;
                int intFriendRelationID = -1;
                objRadioButtonList = (RadioButtonList)e.Item.FindControl("rblstFriends");

                if (objRadioButtonList != null)
                {
                    intFriendRelationID = UserManagementBL.AcceptUserFriendRequest(Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument), this.LoginSessionDO.UserID, objRadioButtonList.SelectedItem.Text);

                    if (intFriendRelationID > 0)
                    {
                        int SentByUserID = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
                        DataTable dtbSenderdetails = null;
                        string SenderEmail = "";

                        dtbSenderdetails = UserManagementBL.GetUserDetails(SentByUserID);
                        if (dtbSenderdetails != null)
                        {
                            SenderEmail = dtbSenderdetails.Rows[0]["UserName"].ToString();
                            SendConfirmationMail(SenderEmail);
                            Response.Redirect("~/Dashboard/Dashboard.aspx",false);                                
                            //GetUserFriendRequests();
                        }
                    }
                }
              break;    

              case "Ignore":
                int intFriendRequestID = -1;
                intFriendRequestID = UserManagementBL.IgnoreUserFriendRequest(Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument), this.LoginSessionDO.UserID);
                GetUserFriendRequests();
                break;
        }
   }
        #endregion

 #region Send confirmation mail
    public void SendConfirmationMail(string email)
    {
        //DataTable dtblUserDetails = UserManagementBL.GetUserByUserName(email);
        //if (dtblUserDetails != null)
        //{
            //int UserID = Convert.ToInt32(dtblUserDetails.Rows[0]["UserID"]);

            //string FirstName = Convert.ToString(dtblUserDetails.Rows[0]["FirstName"]);
            //string LastName = Convert.ToString(dtblUserDetails.Rows[0]["LastName"]);
            string FirstName = this.LoginSessionDO.FirstName;
            string LastName = this.LoginSessionDO.LastName;

            var parameters = new System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, string>();
            parameters.Add("USER_NAME", string.Format("{0} {1}", FirstName, LastName));


            parameters.Add("USER_IMAGE_URL", string.Format(SystemConfiguration.GetSiteURL() + "UserControls/UserPhoto.ashx?UserID={0}", this.LoginSessionDO.UserID));

            string ToAddress = email;
            string subject = FirstName + "  " + LastName + " confirmed you as a friend on Lifetrons.";

            CommonFunctions.CommonFunctions.SendEmail(SystemConfiguration.GetEmailSenderAddress(), ToAddress, subject, CommonFunctions.EmailTemplates.AcceptFriendRequest, parameters);
        //}
    }
    #endregion
```

Here is my pop up box image
[image: Alert]

So how can I close that pop up box immediately after **confirm** button click? Is there any changes in my code?

Comment: you can Send Confirmation Mail Asynchronously and close the dialog.. and later update the status for request

Comment: @amitd thank you for reply I have tried that I call method after response.redirect but it didn't works. pop up box doesn't close

Answer (score 1):

You would do this in JavaScript. <strike>I assume you're already using AJAX to perform the `Confirm` action, otherwise it would just be reloading the page and your popup shouldn't be there anyway (since they're already confirmed?).</strike>

If you have jQuery on the frontend, you can use:

```
$('#confirm-box-id').hide();
```

Without jQuery, you could use:

```
document.getElementById('confirm-box-id').style.display = 'none';
```

---

Re-reading your message, it seems this is just a long running action. You should note that if you do hide this and don't show any indication of progress using the code above, for example, your user may navigate away or close the browser, which *may* cause the action to stop processing or be terminated forcefully server-side so the confirmation would never happen.

Comment: @thank you for reply yes, it's long action. you are right user can navigate to another tab or page

Comment: here I use for pop up **<asp:DataList ID="dlUserFriendRequests" runat="server" Width="100%" 
            onitemdatabound="dlUserFriendRequests_ItemDataBound" 
            onitemcommand="dlUserFriendRequests_ItemCommand" DataKeyField="SentByUserID">**

Comment: @Ajay Okay, and did you try my code to close the popup whilst it's running?

Comment: I am not getting where did I put that query?

Comment: @Ajay In your front-end code, find the 'Confirm' button and assign a click handler on it to call this code..